# Why does this timer print just the final result instead of updating every second?

Tags: python, terminal, carriage-return

I don't understand why the second part of this code is not printing one number by one in steps of 1 second but all at the end of the script (in this case 3 seconds after the beginning of the second part of the code)?

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import time

x       =   0
maxi    =   999999 #I chose a big number to show them scroll

#this part will print all the number on the same line
while x <= maxi:
    print '<{}>\r'.format(x),
    x+=1
print

#this part will print the numbers with a sleep of 1 second for each print
x       =   999998 #I initialized it at this number to only wait 3 seconds
while x <= maxi:
    print '<{}>\r'.format(x),
    x+=1
    time.sleep(1)
print
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably because of buffering.
You can try running your program with `python -u` on the command line, as the man page says

> -u Force  stdin,  stdout  and  stderr  to  be totally unbuffered. [...]

Or you can use `import sys` and put a `sys.stdout.flush()` just after the `print()`.

If you're wondering why that's needed on the second print and not on the first one, it's most likely because of the `sleep`. It blocks execution, so nothing is updated / flushed. I think it's actually also happening on the first one but the updates are much more / faster, so you don't notice it.

Comment: Ok, I understand now why when I put _time.sleep(0.01)_ I saw some numbers but not all ! Thanks